# Efficient replacement for substr?

Tags: php, string, optimization

Let's say we have a very large string `$str`, and we need to pass a significant portion of it (let's say the whole string, but without the first 3 bytes) to a function.  The way to do it with `substr`:

```
consumer_function(substr($str, 3));
```

doesn't seem efficient, because `substr` appears to copy characters from the initial string into a new string before returning the result. Is there any way we could pass a large portion of that string to a function without excessive copying? We can't change the code of that function.

Comment: Do you need the original string and the new (3 char less) string in separate places? Or are you OK with dropping the first 3 chars permanently?

Comment: Well, is it **too slow**? Because if it just "doesn't seem efficient" then *stop worrying about it* - this can be revisited *when* there is a performance test case suggesting it is a bottleneck.

Comment: @mattedgod unfortunately storing these separatelty isn't an option, or it wouldn't be a problem. Plus, 3 characters is just an example, it can actually vary.

Comment: @pst - I expect the size of the string to be in megabytes. Maybe latency-wise it's going to be OK (though I'm not sure about that yet), but memory-wise it means we're going to use twice as much memory per http connection, and I can get a lot of concurrent connections.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. Why do you need _both_ original and result strings as, well, _strings_, in the first place?

Comment: @Grigory In that case you would probably need to move the underlying pointer to where the string is located in memory, if you don't want to copy and unset at least. AFAIK you can't do that in PHP but someone may be able to prove me wrong

Comment: @Grigory Perhaps the entire result can be streamed? It's still in `O(n)`, even with a duplicated string.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a perfect work for streams.

Comment: @pst Thanks for giving me that idea, I will look into it!

Comment: @Grigory if you can't change the consumer function, streams aren't going to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see that there is a problem here.  You're guessing that there is a problem, and you have no reason to think that there is.

"It doesn't seem efficient" is not a problem.  If you measure it and find that it is slow, then you have a problem.  Then, you use a profiler like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) on your code and see if you can find what parts of your code are slow.

If you don't have a problem, then you can't solve it, and guessing at what might maybe possibly seem like it could be potentially slow does not mean you have a problem.

The rules of Optimization Club:

1. The first rule of Optimization Club is, you do not Optimize.
2. The
   second rule of Optimization Club is, you do not Optimize without
   measuring.
3. If your app is running faster than the underlying
   transport protocol, the optimization is over.
4. One factor at a time.
5. No marketroids, no marketroid schedules.
6. Testing will go on as long
   as it has to.
7. If this is your first night at Optimization Club, you
   have to write a test case.

Answer (score 3):

*'Make it work, Then make it perfect'*

**Seriously - Premature Optimization is not a good route to go down.** Unless you feel there is definitely a performance hit - *a hit that is noticeable* - then leave it. Using some little-used trick to do something very common just causes maintenance nightmares when you revisit it.

There are no alternative methods available by default - if you check out the [String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) on the PHP website you can see what is available.

However, you can work on strings using *array notation*:

```
$str[ index ]
```

For example:

```
$str = "abc";
$str[0] // a
$str[1] // b
$str[2] // c
```

Combined with `unset()` it's perfectly possible to manually unset specific items from the string..

```
$str = "abc";
unset( $str[1] ); // $str = "ac" now.
```

Throw in a basic loop and this could be used; in your example you wanted to remove 3 - so you would achieve it like this: (note, array notation = indexes begin at 0!!)

```
for( $i=0; $i<=2; $i++ )
  unset( $str[i] );
```

However, remember you lose the original string - so any data that you may need later on? Yeah, it's gone.

**However - if I was you I'd just stick with `substr()`.**

**Edit:** Grigory has noted in the comments that this doesn't work in PHP 5.3 - which is strange as the [PHP documentation states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **String access and modification by character**
>
> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose. The functions substr() and substr_replace() can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.

So this is really another reason to stick with `substr()` - I'm a bit curious now; so I'm going to try and see if this behaviour which only occurs due to `unset()`. Will report back!

**Update:** As expected, this behaviour is due to `unset()` - which I can't say I'm too surprised with actually.

```
**Fatal errors:** [type:1] -- Cannot unset string offsets -- at line 7
```

You can see my test case at [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nx6-b78) here.

**So in conclusion there are no string functions that can do this natively built in to the language, and you can't do it by manipulating the string character by character. Stick with the recommended way.**

Comment: Your code does not work (in PHP 5.3 at least)

Comment: Weird. String access and modification by character

"*Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose. The functions substr() and substr_replace() can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.*" Still in the PHP docs - no deprecation notices. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Maybe when they say "modify" they don't imply "remove". The PHP interpreter itself explicitly tells me it can't unset string offsets. So, it's not entirely like an array.

Comment: Yep, "Fatal errors: [type:1] -- Cannot unset string offsets -- at line 7". I see now.

Comment: @Grigory - Updated the answer to reflect this and linked to a test case on phpFiddle.

Comment: An old post but still came in handy! I 100% agree with the "make it work then make it perfect" concept. I hadn't realized you can access individual characters in a string as if it was an array. It never even dawned on me. I had never needed it before now. But I am using VSCode and have it set up to format my code automatically. One bit of code is working with binary strings and substr is being reformatted to mb_substr and damaging the binary string. So using $mystring[5].$mystring[6].$mystring[...] works perfectly. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Working on your `$str` and without having to create another variable you could do:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$no;$i++) $str[strlen($str)-$i]=null;
$str=rtrim($str);
```

to shave the last `$no` chars from the end of it

And also:

```
for($i=0;$i<$no;$i++) $str[$i]=null;
$str=ltrim($str);
```

to shave the first chars from it.

### UPDATE:

**TEST A: shaving 30chars from the start of string**

**Test case 1:** substr($str,30)

```
52784749 bytes of data
0.72129082679749s execution time
52903844 bytes of ram used
```

**Test case 2:** loop with null-ing string chars and ltrim

```
52784749 bytes of data
0.23676204681396s execution time
52904276 bytes of ram used
```

**TEST B: shaving 30chars from the end of string**

**Test case 1:** substr($str,0,-30)

```
52784749 bytes of data
0.83467292785645s execution time
52903924 bytes of ram used
```

**Test case 2:** loop with null-ing string chars and rtrim

```
52784749 bytes of data
0.27498316764832s execution time
52904340 bytes of ram used
```

All-in-all a justified question when you're really in need for this kind of micro-optimization, achieved **3x** better processing times with this solution and even better (**up to 40x**) with a smaller dataset of 1.2Mb.
Would need a bit more testing but looks like a viable option.

### UPDATE2:

*as Grigory pointed put that memory is much of an issue over speed and Fergus noticed ltrim()'s mem footprint:*
Unfortunately the use of trim() will get us back to square one with *double the memory used* at some point and only the *speed increase*.

On the other hand, without the use of trim() we'll end up with a string of the same length and with *null characters*, but with both *speed increase* and *memory conservation*.

### UPDATE3:

Also works with **null**, **false** and "**\x08**" (BackSpace chr).
var_dump() reports the string as same length as original but it's value in quotes is what you would expect: only the part you're interested in.

Too bad the question got [closed] :(

Comment: Did you run that code? It gives a PHP error.

Comment: true, i worked on something like this a while back and this was my starting point. seems Fergus got burned too when copying my answer. updating

Comment: ```ltrim()``` leaves him with a similar scenario as ```substr()``` surely? As it returns an entirely new string; meaning there will be two representations in memory at any one time.

Comment: @godka - You've missed my point, If you read what the OP stated [-here-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131363/efficient-replacement-for-substr/14131439#comment19565091_14131363) he wanted to use less memory than ```substr()```. It wasn't execution time (latency) that he was concerned about, but memory usage. This performs essentially identically; as I say - ```ltrim()``` returns a new string - so it would be expected to perform with the same memory overhead.

Comment: @FergusMorrow: you're right! I changed the code to debug with `memory_get_peak_usage()` instead of `memory_get_usage()` and the culprit is trim(), without it you'd use the same amount of mem as $str but with nulled chars... and that would benefit a trim()

Comment: Just got back online, given you +1 (just brought you up to 500, congrats ;)) for some nice work optimizing it actually. I'm just pondering if there's a way to get rid of the pesky null chars. That said, I'm beginning to think this proves the whole 'don't optimize too early point' tbh.

Comment: added another update after some more testing; thanks @FergusMorrow, at this point it's an optimization only if you're willing to accept the length drawback

Answer (score 0):

Based in previous answers. If we can trust that php will try string like arrays, ie, without internal duplication here are 2 solutions more to test. Note that we rewrite the original string `$str` many times.

```
$str         = "abcdefghi"; // a given string 
$set_strip   = 3; // how many chars strip

$strlen  = strlen($str);
$strip   = $strlen - $set_strip;

// test before commit errors    
if ($strip > 0 && $strip <= $strlen)
{
    // SOL. 1.- using str_split with $strip as 2º parameter (trusting strrev() acts efficienly)
    $str             = strrev($str); // reverse string
    $str             = str_split($str, $strip); // split into a array with 2 elements
    $str             = strrev($str[0]); // back to original order

    // SOL. 2.- shortening array $set_strip times
    $str             = str_split($str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $set_strip; $i ++ )
        array_shift($str);

    $str = implode('', $str); // back to string
}
else
    echo "\$set_strip value not allowed = $set_strip, must be non-negative  and < $strlen";
```

Both give us the string: `defghi`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong; But surely re-writing $str multiple times is worse for memory than ```substr()``` though? The OP was concerned about memory implications of ```substr()``` returning a new string - but there are multiple methods doing that here; surely thats worse? I must say, I'm pretty impressed though - I would never have thought of reversing it first!

Comment: The only way to know is by measuring.  Everything else is theory and conjecture.

Comment: @fergus-morrow I really don't think that we can make it better that a built-in function, but try it is fun :) But also think that parser in quite smart to efficiently manage mapping between strings and arrays. If so, ie, always maintain only one memory space to store the original string data, operations like reverse, split, or pop elements may be more fast that duplicate the whole string as OP suggest `substr` do. 8)

Comment: @andy-lester totally  agreed, working with huge strings it is sure that we obtain very different memory usage results.